# Storing secret Q&A - hash or plain text.

Tags: php, database, authentication

My passwords are using sha512 but secret question and answers are plain text. The question is: Do I need to hash the secret answers? If so what datatype to use for it, would it still be char(128)?I assume secret question has to be plain text right?

Answer (score 5):

Just get rid of the secret questions, they're a pointless measure:

1. they do not increase security, they actually diminish them as it's quite easy to find the answer especially because, as you said, there will be stupid usere around who will use "what is your favourite pet?" as a "secret" question.
2. they can be frustrating as you may spell the answer slightly differently (or uppercase/lowercase) when trying to recover your password.
3. if your password is hashed you cannot give the password back to the user, you'll have to send him/her an email with a new password or a link to change it, so why don't you just let the user enter his email address in the first place?
4. it's just another extra field to fill up upon registration. There's already too many...

Comment: I agree. Secret questions/answers suck! And nobody remembers those (becayse nobody fills actual truth in, because that would be stupid). So eh **what he said** =)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't really have to hash either.  If a user wants to reset their password via question/answer, it should send out an email with a link to do so.  If an attacker managed to get their hands on the questions/answers, it still wouldn't help them unless they already had access to the user's email, which means that all bets are pretty much off already.  You could hash the answers if you wanted to, and they would be stored in the same manner as the passwords are since they'd wind up in the same format.

One question though, do the users type in their own question or do they select from a list?  If from a list, why not just use an identifier for which question was used, and have the potential questions either in another table or hard coded into the script?

Comment: Users type their own question. I have fund list questions to be poor always. They always ask the same lame questions like month's maiden name, favorite pet, etc which anyone close to you should know.

Comment: If users can type their own questions, it negates the **entire point** of the secret question/answer principle =) Ditch it!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I wanted to add some thoughts on nico's answer (I'm too new to add comments). Security questions are useful when users no longer have access to the email address they registered with (it happens frequently). You need some other way to identify them or they will never get back to their account.

You can mitigate the risk of mis-entry by normalizing the inputs (lowercase, trim leading/trailing spaces, etc.).

Back to OP, if you still use them, one reason *not* to hash them is exactly nico's second point - if the answer is "St. Cloud" and the person types "St Cloud", a poorly-written system might deny the reset. But an administrator would see that the answer is obviously correct if the answers weren't hashed. If the answers were hashed, there would be no way to know if the user was even close.

Comment: I disagree. This is definitely an **increase in security risks**. The whole point of hashing passwords is to prevent someone to retrieve them in case he got access to the DB. If you store secret answers in plain text then you lose this security. If I lost access to my old email address I will just register with a new one. If the user does not have access to the mail he will not receive the email with the link for the new password anyway, so what's the point of the secret question? And if you give me the password directly it means you store it in plain text, which is not secure.

Comment: A hacker would also have to have access to the user's email account to *automatically* get new credentials - merely having the plaintext SA is not enough. If they have access to the email, all bets are off as Phoenix said. But if the authorized user contacts me with the correct SA and I am *also* able to verify other details about them (say, the last 4 digits of a credit card) then I consider their having the SA, and my ability to quickly match it visually, to be another tool in ensuring their identity. I don't understand your last sentence - I never mentioned plaintext passwords.

Comment: if the user has lost access to his email, then the whole point of a secret question would be to give him back his password, therefore you would have to store it in plaintext. If the user has access to his email, you just email him a link, with no need to have a useless extra step that will give a lot of false positives.

Comment: Now I get it what you're saying. In my case, the point of the secret question is **not** to give him back *his* password. I don't have that infomation (it's hashed). The point is to give him a *new* temporary password, which is stored hashed. He can change it later if he wants.

Comment: well, but if the hacker gets access to the secret question he will get the temporary password and change it to whatever he wants (this is always thinking that the user has lost access to the email obviously). In summary, my point is: if the user has lost access to his email address, too bad for him! ;)

Comment: If the hacker gets access to the secret question/answer, he **cannot** get the temporary password. He would also have to have access to the email account or hack the mail server. Otherwise he has to social engineer us, and that's a different discussion. As for "too bad" - for some services I see what you are saying, but here we have paid digital access to content. So there has to be a way to verify identity and restore access. Google uses mobile phone numbers now; I wonder what they do if you lose your password and forgot you changed mobile numbers in the past. Maybe they say too bad. :)